# Credit Card using Android Adaptive Payments MLP

Tags: android, paypal-adaptive-payments, credit-card, chained-payments, adaptive-parallel-payment

a bit embarrassing, but after having successfully implemented single and parallel adaptive payments in our Android App (pay using PayPal email), using the PayPal MLP (https://github.com/paypal/sdk-packages/tree/gh-pages/MPL), now we are looking how to use the funding type "credit card" as a "guest payment" option (where the buyer does not need to have a PayPal account to make payment with his credit card).

While seeing the documentation for the funding type "credit card" (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/) we simply cant find the UI which we assume we have to use and integrate anywhere in the MLP library.

Does anyone have any idea how/where to get that?

Comment: You can't make your own ui that communicates with the api?

Comment: Thanks, can I ask if you speak of any experience with the PayPal API? Yes, WE can, that's an easy one, but as we understand it, for security reasons you have to use the UI provide in the library and you will NOT have control of ANYTHING once the view is handed over to the PayPal library until the process is completed and UI control is handed back. So, for the period of handling the payment process you are stuck with what the library gives and allows you to do. If that is incorrect, I am honestly happy to learn.